# A way to empty a UIImageView on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` on a `UITableViewCell`
When I don't have an image to view, I want it to be gone.
I've implemented this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ((item.content_image != nil) && (item.content_image != (id)[NSNull null]))
    {
        [cell.imageContentImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL item.content_image]] ;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.imageContentImage = nil;
    }
}
```

I got a report from one user, for a wrong image in the cell (it seems to duplicate the image from other cells).

The thing is that it doesn't happen on simulator or a device I can debug it, so my question turned theoretical:

Is assigning `nil` to the `UIImageView` is the right way to go? is there a "more correct" way?

Comment: What method is the posted code in?

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath. Edited the code...

Comment: Well first, I would definitely set the image of the imageView to nil and not the imageView itself. If you reuse your cell you could have unexpected behaviors.

Comment: so what's the difference between nil out the image and nil the entire UIImageView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems here. First you're doing a pointer comparison to an object of type `NSNull` when I think what you're looking for is something more like this:

```
if(item.content_image && ![item.content_image isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {}
```

Second, the reason you might see duplicate images is because you are not allocating a new cell each time, you are `dequeing` a reusable cell which may have old stuff left over in it. The easiest way would be to simply `nil` out the image property of the image view right away and then only assign an image if it exists.

```
cell.imageContentImage.image = nil;
if(item.content_image && ![item.content_image isEqual:[NSNull null]])
{
    [cell.imageContentImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL urlWithString:item.content_image]];
}
```

Comment: so what's the difference between nil out the image and nil the entire UIImageView?

Comment: Setting the image property on the UIImageView to `nil`will remove the image, but not destroy the image view (or the pointer to the image view, depending on how it's created). These cells are reusable so anything you do you want to make sure is non-destructive and won't leave the cell in an invalid state if it gets pulled back out of the queue for different data later.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning nil to the UIImage property for a UIImageView is perfectly fine.  Perhaps if you're seeing an incorrect image (duplicated image) in a cell it's being cached?  The safest way to ensure that doesn't happen is when dequeuing a cell in your cellForRowAtIndexPath() method to always set the cell's image to nil first thing .... then assign the image if appropriate.  The only way you'd get a "duplicate" then is if there's an issue with the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't want to write code in ELSE block in this case. But if you want to hide the UIImageView this is a better way.

```
imageView.hidden = YES;
```